# Why is IE9/Firefox showing a different font size in relation to other browsers?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, font-size

I'm programming the CSS of a site, and realized that the Internet Explorer 9 is showing different font size in relation to other browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE7 and IE8).

I've tried using some RESETS, and I am specifying the font in `px`, but IE9 still shows the difference in font size.

I've tried using `font-size` in `pt`, `in`, percentage, but had no success.

I changed the font before (Georgia, Times New Roman, Verdana). Some of them are shown larger, others are smaller in IE9.

I checked the zoom settings and text size in IE. They are 100% and medium respectively.

To illustrate, I created a simple HTML and CSS as you can see the code below. How to solve this problem? Thanks!

The problem:

[image]

Code:

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
    AAAAA BBBBB CCCCC DDDDD EEEEE FFFFF GGGGG HHHHH IIIII JJJJJ KKKKK LLLLL MMMMM NNNNNN OOOOO PPPPP QQQQQ
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/* RESET */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/* END OF RESET */

body {
    background-image:url(GreenLine.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

Comment: Notice red stripes in non-ie browsers - http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/ - those are caused by differences in font rendering (and aggravated by red background, which makes those browsers look buggy)

Comment: You might do better with this question on a more design oriented site like doctype.com, since it looks like it's related more to font rendering than CSS.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you checking it against? The answer is "important". I'd expect the Firefox rendering to match IE9.

Comment: Screw it, I've just answered anyway despite the discrepancy in your description - IE9 and Firefox should match, unless you're using a version of Firefox older than 4.

Comment: thirtydot, This is true. I updated Firefox to the latest version. Now Firefox is showing just as IE9.

I updated the other browsers (Safari and Chrome), but the difference remains.

Comment: @Bruno Bastos: I've covered the reason this is happening in my answer. Just in case you missed it, check the [last link in my answer](http://blog.mozilla.com/nattokirai/2011/08/11/directwrite-text-rendering-in-firefox-6/). **There is no way to fix this.**

Answer (score 7):

IE9 uses [DirectWrite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectWrite) to render text, and other browsers do not (except for Firefox 4+).

That is the reason for the slightly different size of the text between the two browsers.

There is no way to make the text the same size.

Read this: http://www.basschouten.com/blog1.php/font-rendering-gdi-versus-directwrite

And this, **particularly** the "Hinting and spacing differences" section: https://web.archive.org/web/20120603023828/https://blog.mozilla.org/nattokirai/2011/08/11/directwrite-text-rendering-in-firefox-6/

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the `body{font-size:medium; line-height:1em;}`
 where the font-size will be of `16px` now and use percent on `p` tag to increase or decrease the `font-size`. 
To be sure of limit the width of the `p` tag.

```
P{max-width:40%; font-size:86%; line-height:1.2em;}
```

Comment: Take care, I've edited two typos in one line of your code. A StackOverflow answer should include working code, not one that is getting others into new trouble.

Answer (score -2):

Two possible things, both untested:

1. try changing the doctype to something other than xhtml transitional.  See if the HTML5 doctype renders it better. `<!DOCTYPE html>`
2. try using only `font-family: monospace;` to see if it is a font issue.

**EDIT**

If those do not work **and** you cannot find a solution, you might want to serve IE9 a different `font-size` using conditional comments.

Comment: I changed the DOCTYPE and font family to monospace, and the problem continues.

I changed the font before (Georgia, Times New Romam, Verdana). Some of them are shown larger, others are smaller in IE9.

PS: I checked the zoom settings and text size in IE. They are 100% and medium respectively.

Thanks.