# Custom font looks smaller in Chrome browser?

Tags: html, css, browser, font-size

Below is the sample font I'm using:
http://wthdesign.net/acf/test.html

If I open the page using chrome the font looks smaller. However when I open it using either Firefox or Internet explorer the fonts look bigger....

How can I standardize the font size in all the browsers?

Here is what I get:

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. Check the zoom level of browsers. (Ctrl and + or Ctrl and -) .

Comment: Yes I tried control+0 to reset to default size (without the magnifying glass on the right side of the browser). But the font still appear smaller

Comment: @KK, in order to achieve the same size as firefox and IE in chrome. I will need to zoom in twice(125%).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7500732/2000051 Check the answer.